# Type error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\SecurityExtension::__construct() must be an instance of

Tags: php, symfony

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\SecurityExtension::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface, instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker given, called in /path/to/project/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 5090.

I still continue to have this error but when I update my composer

```
composer update
```

all work right.

How can I fix definitely it?
Thanks.

Comment: what symfony version are you using?

Comment: Symfony version 3.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SecurityContextInterface` as a first argument of `SecurityExtension` has been deprecated since symfony 2.7, and it has been removed in symfony 3. You can choose to downgrade to symfony2, or update your code to symfony 3. In your case, i think that you've upgrade your symfony version, but you forgot to *clear your cache*: `composer clearcache`.

Comment: So I don't understand why sometimes all work right and then i have this problem.

Comment: can you do an example?

Comment: I don't know after what it happens but yesterday evening it works, today I get this error.

Comment: you upgraded your symfony version, didn't you? rebuilding the container didn't work?

Comment: No i didn't update my symfony version. I started this project with symfony 3.0.1

Comment: can you share your `composer.json` file?

Comment: `"symfony/twig-bridge": "2.3.x",`, edit that to 3.0.1. How did you create the project?